# Delete record with bootstrap modalbox confirmation using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, codeigniter-2

I want to delete my record from database by giving an alert box which is bootstrap modal box.
i am using codeigniter, i tried but it did not worked. plz Help..

Here is my Controller:

```
function deleteImage($id = NULL){           
    $this->config_mdl->delete_image($id);           
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Image Deletion Successful !!');
}
```

Here is my Model:

```
function delete_image($id)
{
    return $this->db->delete('tbl_gallery', array('image_id' => $id));
}
```

Here is my View:

```
<div id="confirmDelete" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-lebelledby="confirmDeleteLebel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure want to delete this record?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="confirm">OK</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caption img-gallery-caption">
        <?php
        $attributes = array('data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#confirmDelete', 'data-title' => 'Delete Image', 'data-message' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this Image?');
        echo anchor('config/editImage', '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>', $attributes); 
        echo anchor('config/deleteImage/'.$image->image_id, '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>');
        ?>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#confirmDelete").on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
     $(this).find('#confirm').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that you can go in inside the  `$("#confirmDelete").on...`

You can use ajax in the call

```
$("#confirmDelete").on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
    // Search  the 'id'

    $.post(
        'deleteImage/'+id,
         '',
         funcion(data){
            // some data tha you want to receive from the server
         },

        'json');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting href value of button! button doesn't have href attribute so instead convert your button into anchor tag and it will work!